# How to make electron works offline with realm

Tags: javascript, electron, realm, electron-builder, renderer

I have installed realm and require the package in the renderer process and I'm able to make the queries. Now I want to make it work offline with my electron build, and there are no such docs for that. Can anybody explain to me how to include the realm in the build and make it work offline.

Comment: Store the data in a "cache" ?! Like a json file or like that

Comment: @Marc do you know how to make it work with realm?

Comment: There is no huge diffrent. Just store that what you would write in the file in the db.

Comment: The question is unclear. Make *what* work offline?

Comment: @Marc I'm clear with the part of saving my data in DB. But the question is, Are you aware that How I can make local DB to be downloaded with the bundle of my electron app. So that it will be there on a user's computer if they are downloading my app.

Comment: @Jay please read the comment above, I hope it will be clear now.

Comment: Are you asking about [Bundled Realms](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#read-only-realms) to be included with your app?

Comment: @Jay Yes, I'm talking about the Bundled realm

Comment: So... The answer is in the documentation, right? The question is pretty vague though - is there more to the question? Do you have some code we can assist with as that's what SO is for - coding specific questions.